# When to index a Core Data attribute?

Tags: performance, core-data, indexing, nspredicate, nssortdescriptor

In which cases should I index a Core Data attribute?

1. When I'm sorting by it?

   ```
   fetchRequest.sortDescriptors =
   [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor
                             sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES
                             selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)]];
   ```
2. When I'm filtering by it?

   ```
   fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                             @"name BEGINSWITH[cd] %@", searchString];
   ```
3. Any other cases?

Answer (score 1):

I think, you can do it in both cases, presuming that you will work a lot with that attribute and it is itself big and will cost a lot to make a fetch without indexed column.